# How do I access a ref in a functional child component that is wrapped in React-Redux's connect function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a parent class component and a child functional component. The child component has an element that I would like to focus when another element on the page (a modal) is closed. In order to achieve this I am trying to forward a ref to the child component. However, the child component is wrapped in React-Redux's connect function. I've tried a couple different methods of ref forwarding and I haven't been able to get it working as of yet.

I can't update any of my package versions. I'm on React 16.6.0, Redux 4.0.1, and React-Redux 5.1.0.

Below you'll find a representation of what I'm describing.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  ...
  this.childRef = React.createRef();
 }
 render() {
  return(
   <Child ref={childRef}/>
  )
 }
}


const Child = forwardRef(props, ref) => {
 return(
  <input ref={ref} />
 )
}

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps,
 null,
 { forwardRef: true}
)(Child);
```

With the setup posted above I can access the ref in the parent component but it points to connect, not the wrapped child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the use case for `forwardRef` (You can use it but you don't need).

Your problem is that you [can't name](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5744) a `prop` as `ref` (or `key`), just rename it and you should be fine.

```
<Child parentRef={childRef}/>


const Child = ({ parentRef }) => <input ref={parentRef} />
```

Comment: Insane. I always make these simple mistakes. Thank you!